# Linear Transformation of polynomial with ordered bases

Tags: matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

I have tried to solve the following:-
Let $P_2 -> P_2$ be defined by
$$T(a+bx+cx^2) = 2b+3cx+(a-b)x^2$$
Find the matrix of transformation w.r.t ordered bases $B_1= \left\{x^2, x^2+x, x^2+x+1\right\}$ and $B_2 = \left\{1,x,x^2 \right\}$

What I have done :-
Considering $(1,0,0) (0,1,0)\;\; \text{and}\;\; (0,0,1)$ as the standard ordered basis
So,
When
 $T(1+0x+0x^2)  2b+3cx+(a-b)x^2=x^2$

$T(0+1x+0x^2) 2b+3cx+(a-b)x^2=2-x^2$

$T(0+0x+1x^2)\;\; \text{gives}\;\; 3x$
Therefore the matrix is:-
0 2 0
0 0 3
1 -1 0
Now the transition matrices are :-
B1 
0 1 1
0 0 1
1 1 1
B2
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
As the formula
Pe^-1 <-B2 At Pe<-B1
Inverse of B2 x Matrix from polynomial x B1 gave me the following result:-
0 0 2
3 3 3
0 0 -1
Is it correct?

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial. At the moment, your question is unreadable.

Comment: why are you using standared order basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ here space is $P_2$ vector space of polynomials of degree less then or equal to $2$

Comment: You can check your own work. If I understand your result correctly, it says that $T(x^2)=3(x^2+x)$. Does it? Also check that you’ve gotten the basis vectors in the right order.